# Ruby nested hash find duplicates

Tags: ruby, xml

I am trying to figure out a way to loop through this hash

```
students = {
  first: {ID: 1, UPN: "S535449032228", forename: "James", surname: "Penn", email: "jpenn@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "S535449032229", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 3", lang: "ENG"},
  second: {ID: 2,UPN: "K535449032230", forename: "Sandy", surname: "Snow", email: "ssnow@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "K535449032231", gender: "Female", yearGroup: "Year 2", lang: "ENG"},
  third: {ID: 3, UPN: "J535449032230", forename: "Mike", surname: "Myers", email: "myers@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "J535449032230", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 5", lang: "ENG"},
  fourth: {ID: 4, UPN: "P535449032228", forename: "Penny", surname: "Dyer", email: "pdyer@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "P535449032229", gender: "Female", yearGroup: "Year 4", lang: "ENG"},
  fith: {ID: 5, UPN: "D535449032230", forename: "Roger", surname: "Smith", email: "rogers@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "D535449032231", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 1", lang: "ENG"},
  sixth: {ID: 6, UPN: "E535449032230", forename: "Johnny", surname: "Johnson", email: "jjohnson@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "E535449032230", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 3", lang: "ENG"},
  seventh: {ID: 7, UPN: "S695449032228", forename: "Robert", surname: "Pennfold", email: "rpennfold@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "S535449033229", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 2", lang: "ENG"},
  eighth: {ID: 8, UPN: "R535449032230", forename: "Chelsey", surname: "Luigi", email: "chelluigi@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "R535449032231", gender: "Female", yearGroup: "Year 4", lang: "ENG"}
}
```

and find if there are duplicates in the emails, however I am running into issues of not being able to figure out the correct method to code this.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions that I can attempt?

I am using Nokogiri gem as I will be creating an xml file, but wish to check for duplicates first

Comment: Might not be the best idea to build a hash with such keys in the first place, especially when it already gets "fifth" wrong.

Comment: what do you want to do with duplicates? Do you want them to be just printed out, or you want to remove them from hash?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions that I can attempt?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account the structure of your hash you can do the following:

```
# get all users emails as an array. _hash_key (first, second etc.) param is ignored
emails = students.map { |_hash_key, student| student[:email] }

# detect all emails which have more than one occurrence
emails.select { |email| emails.count(email) > 1 }.uniq
```

As a side note: for your structure it is easier to use array instead of hash, because `first`, `second`, `third` etc. keys are not making much sense and not helping you code your program easier. `Array` makes it easier to loop through your data.

```
students = [
  {ID: 1, UPN: "S535449032228", forename: "James", surname: "Penn", email: "jpenn@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "S535449032229", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 3", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 2, UPN: "K535449032230", forename: "Sandy", surname: "Snow", email: "ssnow@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "K535449032231", gender: "Female", yearGroup: "Year 2", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 3, UPN: "J535449032230", forename: "Mike", surname: "Myers", email: "myers@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "J535449032230", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 5", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 4, UPN: "P535449032228", forename: "Penny", surname: "Dyer", email: "pdyer@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "P535449032229", gender: "Female", yearGroup: "Year 4", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 5, UPN: "D535449032230", forename: "Roger", surname: "Smith", email: "rogers@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "D535449032231", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 1", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 6, UPN: "E535449032230", forename: "Johnny", surname: "Johnson", email: "jjohnson@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "E535449032230", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 3", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 7, UPN: "S695449032228", forename: "Robert", surname: "Pennfold", email: "rpennfold@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "S535449033229", gender: "Male", yearGroup: "Year 2", lang: "ENG"},
  {ID: 8, UPN: "R535449032230", forename: "Chelsey", surname: "Luigi", email: "chelluigi@stanleypark.com", formerUPN: "R535449032231", gender: "Female", yearGroup: "Year 4", lang: "ENG"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, this worked and I took your advice on using an array instead, and that did help me code the rest of the program too. using the array and now with the knowledge of the select and map, it helped me understand how to tackle similar problems throughout my code thank you,.

Answer (score 0):

```
students.values.group_by { |e| e[:email] }.count == students.count
```